# jQuery: Foreach element href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title sounds confusing.. but im sure this is possible!

I have one button, `(id='downloadAll')` and many `<a href="..." class="link"></a>` on my page. What i want to do, for the purpose of finding out how to do this.. is to do something logic like this.

```
var hrefs = ALL OF THE ELEMENTS WITH CLASS 'link';
foreach(hrefs){
 alert(this.attr('href'));
}
```

Basically for each of the elements with a class, i want to get the value of each one... in tern.
Yes, i do have jquery on the page - am hoping to make use of this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("a.link").each(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: Ah! haha thanks! i found that literally 2 seconds before you posted ;) thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this:

```
$.each(hrefs, function(){
  alert(this.href);
});
```